# Connecting Classic ASP to SQL Server 2012

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, sql-server-2012

I have 2 servers, a win2000+ Classic ASP application server, the other is Server 2012 with a SQL 2012 instance.

On the application server I can create an ODBC DSN (name is "test") to connect to the SQL instance, and access database (mdb). I use "test" to link tables in B, so the connection is fine. But on my ASP page I cannot connect to the SQL instance, and an error message is displayed: "SQL Server does not exist or access denied".

Here's my code:

```
Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.open "DSN=test;UID=user;PWD=pwd;DATABASE=test"
conn.close
set conn = nothing
response.write "ok"
```

Comment: What happens if you use an oledb connection string for SQL Server (eg `Conn.open "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=yourServerAddress;Initial Catalog=yourDataBase;
User Id=yourUsername;Password=yourPassword;"`

Comment: use oledb got error: 
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80004005' 

[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied

Comment: I just not understand why in same server a access mdb can use ODBC to connect sql2012 but Asp page can not.

Comment: Have you tried saving your System DSN as a file DSN to see if there's anything missing that you haven't noticed?

Comment: file DSN is same as System DSN. Access  database can connect to sql2012 through that odbc, but Asp can not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
Dim MM_MyServer_STRING

MM_MyServer_STRING = "SERVER=test;DATABASE=test;user id=user;password=pwd"

Set ConnectMe = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
ConnectMe.ActiveConnection = MM_MyServer_STRING
```